# Rails Elasticsearch with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I use Elasticsearch in my Rails application (elasticsearch-model, elasticsearch-rails gems). I wrote a simple search:

```
def search
    @posts = params[:term] ? Post.search(params[:term]) : [] 
    render json: @posts
end
```

It works good. But I made some fixes in order to do search among 'deleted=false' and 'enabled=true' subset then :

```
def search
    @posts = params[:term] ? Post.existing.enabled.search(params[:term]) : [] 
    render json: @posts
end
```

Post

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

    scope :existing, ->{ where(deleted: false) }
    scope :enabled,  ->{ where(enabled: true) }
end
Post.import
```

It doesn't work - I see the same results as in the previous case(with any value in 'deleted' and 'existing' columns. How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change how your `search` method works.

```
@posts = params[:term] ? Post.search(params[:term], existing: true, enabled: true) : []
```

Post model

```
def self.search query, options = {}
  __add_filter = lambda do |f|
    search_definition[:filter][:and] ||= []
    search_definition[:filter][:and] |= [f]
  end
  search_definition = {
    query: {},
    filter: {}
  }
  if options[:existing]
    __add_filter.({ term: {'deleted' => false}})
  end
  if options[:enabled]
    __add_filter.({ term: {'enabled' => true}})
  end
  unless query.blank?
    search_definition[:query] = {
      # add your query logic
    }
  else
    search_definition[:query] = { match_all: {}}
  end
  __elasticsearch__.search(search_definition)
end
```

You could also check [elastic_search example](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/blob/templates/elasticsearch-rails/lib/rails/templates/searchable.rb)

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.search query, options = {}
  search_definition = {
    query: {},
    filter: {}
  }
  __add_filter = lambda do |f|
    search_definition[:filter][:and] ||= []
    search_definition[:filter][:and] |= [f]
  end
  if options[:existing]
    __add_filter.({ term: {'deleted' => false}})
  end
  if options[:enabled]
    __add_filter.({ term: {'enabled' => true}})
  end
  unless query.blank?
    search_definition[:query] = {
      # add your query logic
    }
  else
    search_definition[:query] = { match_all: {}}
  end
  __elasticsearch__.search(search_definition)
end
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)